# Which is a suitable architecture?

Tags: java, database, sockets

I have tested a socket connection programme with the idea where the socket connection will be one separate thread by itself and then it will enqueue and another separate thread for dbprocessor will pick from the queue and run through a number of sql statement. So I notice here is where the bottle neck that the db processing. I would like to get some idea is what I am doing the right architecture or I should change or improve on my design flow?

The requirement is to capture data via socket connections and run through a db process then store it accordingly.

```
public class cServer
{
 private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> databaseQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

   class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
        ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
          this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
        }


       // gets data from an inbound connection and queues it for databse update

       public void run(){
         databaseQueue.add(message); // put to db queue
       }
    }
    class DatabaseProcessor implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
             // open database connection
             createConnection();
             while (true){
               message = databaseQueue.take(); // keep taking message from the queue add by connectionhandler and here I will have a number of queries to run in terms of select,insert and updates.
             }
    }

    void createConnection(){
        System.out.println("Crerate Connection");
        connCreated = new Date();
        try{
        dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1?"+"user=user1&password=*******");
        dbconn.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
        catch(Throwable ex){
           ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
     }
    }

    public void main()
    {
    new Thread(new DatabaseProcessor()).start(); //calls the DatabaseProcessor
    try 
    {
      final ServerSocket serverSocketConn = new ServerSocket(8000);             
      while (true){
        try{
            Socket socketConn1 = serverSocketConn.accept();
            new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socketConn1)).start();                     
       }
       catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace(System.out);
       }
      }
    } 
    catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: An architecture _must_ be driven by it's requirements. Since you have given no requirements (at all), the only way to determine suitability of a proposed architecture is if it will completely not work, or it will.

Comment: Where/how is your queue defined?  Is it thread safe?  Is it synchronised?

Comment: @alek I have added the class name cServer and below is the where I define the queue

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your architecture sounds correct. You need to make sure that your two threads are synchronised correctly when reading/writing from/to the queue.

I am not sure what you mean by "bottle neck that the db processing"?  If DB processing takes a long time and and you end up with a long queue, there's not much you can do apart from having multiple threads performing the DB processing (assuming the processing can be parallelised, of course) or do some performance tuning in the DB thread.

If you post some specific code that you believe is causing the problem, we can have another look.

Comment: I have put some snippet of my codes. Can you see anything wrongly design here? I have tried to generate another extra db thread by adding a line of this new Thread(new DatabaseProcessor()).start(); but I end up getting error showing me the mysql driver does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard (read 'Impossible') to judge a architecture without the requirements. So I will just make some up:

Maximum Throughput:
Don't use a database, write to a flatfile, possibly stored on something fast like a solid state disc.

Guaranteed Persistence (If the user gets an answer not consisting of an error, the data must be stored securely):
Make the whole thing single threaded, save everything in a database with redundant discs. Make sure you have a competent DBA who knows about Back up and Recovery. Test those on regular intervals.

Minimum time for finishing the user request:
Your approach seems reasonable.

Minimum time for finishing the user request + Maximizing Throughput + Good Persistence (what ever that means):
Your approach seems good. You might plan for multiple threads processing the DB requests. But test how much (more) throughput you actually get and where precisely the bottleneck is (Network, DB CPU, IO, Lock contention ...). Make sure you don't introduce bugs by using a concurrent approach.

Comment: I have added a snippet of my codes. basically the socket gets data then I run through a number of sql queries and finally is stored into a the db. the db processing is indeed a long process with a number of queries involve for verification purposes.

Comment: Given those requirements, you might consider a NoSQL database such as Apache Cassandra, which has very high throughput, with durable writes, but is more powerful than flat files (has indexing etc) and is horizontally scalable to multiple nodes.

Comment: @I am now using mysql. So what improvement can I do on this structure now?

Comment: To quote myself: "It's hard (read 'Impossible') to judge [or improve] a architecture without the requirements."

Comment: @jens my requirement is that it will get data via socket connection. thereafter it will process the data by performing some db processing to check some event message etc. thereafter it will then send sms or email accordingly. hope is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two threads for this simple task. Just read the socket and execute the statements.

Comment: in order to avoid complexity we have removed 2 more threads that are one dealing with email and sms accordingly.so do you still recommend to just go with one single thread? Beside that we notice the good part of this queue mechanism is that the order of incoming message stays intact as per sending mechanism. Thus the insertion into the db follows the sequence of the message arrival.

Comment: @user837306. The order that is preserved by the queue is just the order that is already present coming in from the socket. This is not an added value.

Comment: I do agree with that too let me re-look with my team. But beside this remember I told you we too have a thread for sms and another for email.so your suggestion is to put everything under one thread and keep the sms and email separate function is that the direction you are guiding to move towards? What difference will be between this method and the single thread in terms of memory effect or performance? We find these method performs quite fast but the problem start when the queue builds up.

Comment: @user837306 My suggestion was to combine the socket-reading and database update threads. The onus is on you or your team to justify the cost and overhead of making these into separate threads. You haven't done so here. It is pointless.

Comment: we removed the two thread and put the reading and db processing all into one thread. so we did the time processing comparison with multi thread and single thread roughly both comes to same around 40seconds. the good part in single thread there is no queue and each socket connection gets one new db connection so the overall effect is not many data will be waiting in queue. One more thing each socket connection will deliver 5 different messages so now each batch will be processed by one connection that itself also cause some kind of queue effect right any room for improvement here?

Comment: @user837306 what 'kind of queue effect'?

Comment: is ok that "queue" is actually due to the input values are also coming one after another which is not avoidable. So what is your main reason to keep things in one thread?